# Dynamically update CSS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dynamic-css

I have my HTML set up like this

```
<div.... repeats in a loop... >
     ....
    <div ng-init="setWidthOfTimeLine(machine)" style="height:2px;" class="background-grey" >
        <div ng-style="setWidthOfTime"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my controller I have something like this:

```
$scope.setWidthOfTimeLine = function(machine){

            var length = (machine.machineStatus).length - 1;
            var widthGreen = (length/8) *100;

                $scope.setWidthOfTime = {
                    background : "green",
                    width : widthGreen + '%',
                    height : '2px'
                }
                console.log($scope.setWidthOfTime);
        }
```

Although I can see proper CSS being generated on the console. It is not being applied to the DOM, any ideas what I am missing?

Console:

```
Object {background: "green", width: "12.5%"} 
Object {background: "green", width: "25%"} 
Object {background: "green", width: "25%"} 
Object {background: "green", width: "37.5%"}
```

EDIT : Fixed half the issue by setting height in the setWidthOfTime  variable, but now it is taking the last value(37.5%) for all the width values.

Comment: was just testing some theory, did not make a difference either ways.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the problem in a Fiddle? Can't see the problem here.

Comment: Looks like something to do with scope inheritance. `ngRepeat` creates new scope for each entry. For each entry scope, a property `setWidthOfTime` is created. Your controller, however, seems like setting the `setWidthOfTime` property in the parent scope of all the entry scopes created by `ngRepeat`. Just for the sake of investigating, does it work if you take out `ngRepeat`?

Comment: No, did not seem to help, ng-repeat is also nested here. the structure is too complex for me to replicate in a fiddle :(

Comment: @tamakisquare Edited the question, problem is half solved.

Comment: Where is your controller being defined and do you have nested controllers? if your controller is defined outside of the `ng-repeat` then you're overwriting your `setWidthOfTime` with every repeat, which is why all of them are set to 37.5%.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions that might help here.

Instead of setting `setWidthOfTime` as a property of scope, try setting it to a property of **an object** of  scope. Say we call this object `foo`, then you would first initialize `foo` with a property named `setWidthOfTime` in the controller. From this point on, you'll read from or write to `foo.setWidthOfTime`, regardless in controller or view. The key here is never overwrite `foo` once it's initialized. (I recommend getting yourself familiarize with [How scope inheritance works](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance))

Use ngController's new syntax, *as propertyName* (only available in newer versions of AngularJS). You would have something like `ng-controller="MyController as myctrl"` and then `ng-style="myctrl.setWidthOfTime`. This new syntax is a new acquaintance and I have not used it myself, but I have read about it and see the usefulness of it. Give it a shot if it's available in your AngularJS version. ([Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `machine` is what you get from your `ngRepeat` directive, try this:

```
<div.... ng-repeat="machine in $scope.machines"... >
     ....
    <div style="height:2px;" class="background-grey" >
        <div ng-style="setWidthOfTimeLine(machine)"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.setWidthOfTimeLine = function(machine){
    var length = (machine.machineStatus).length - 1;
    var widthGreen = (length/8) *100;
    var widthOfTime = {
        background : "green",
        width : widthGreen + '%',
        height : '2px'
    }
    console.log(widthOfTime);
    return widthOfTime;
}
```